# Scrolling without moving main content

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to be able to scroll a div without really moving the page contents (to trigger animations).
My idea was to use position fixed on the main content of the page (the main content is only 100vh of height) and then create a secondary div that has absolute position and scales through the whole page.

Here my files:

```
<div className="App">
   <div className="test">
      Hello
   </div>

   <div className="scrollArea" ref={scrollArea}/>
</div>
```

And my css

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.test{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5vh;
}

.scrollArea{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200vw;
  z-index: 99;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This works. I can scroll without moving my content inside of my "test" div. For some reason however the scrollbar gets attached to body instead of the "App" div. Why does it behave like that? If i add an onScroll event to my "App" div i don't register any changes. Can someone explain how to change this behavior? I tried using overflow: hidden on body and html, but then the scrollbar didn't work anymore at all.

Comment: I cannot imagine, where is differrence between scrollbar on body and app, if both are height 100%?

Comment: I also don't exactly understand but doing position: relative on app did the trick. The scrollbar is now attached to the div instead of the body :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to hide the scrollbar?

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
html::-webkit-scrollbar ,body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.test{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5vh;
}

.scrollArea{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200vh;
  z-index: 99;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
   <div class="test">
      Hello
   </div>

<div class="scrollArea" ref={scrollArea}>
  <p>
  1
  </p><p>
  2
  </p><p>
  3
  </p>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes i was also trying to hide the scrollbar but my actual concern was that the scrollbar is always getting attached to the body, not to the div with the App class

Comment: I found the problem: I had to add position: relative to the .App css, i don't exactly know why, but then the scrollbar got added to the div :)

Comment: yes that makes sense. the position of `scrollArea` is `absolute` which made it absolute relative to it's nearest parent's positioning. If no positioning was set on any parent element for `scrollArea` the parent becomes `html` by default.